# How do I convert this JSON datetime?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, datetime

The following string was returned from a JSON formatted response object and I want to parse it into something useful: /Date(1283457528340)/

How do I parse it using JavaScript into something user-friendly?

Comment: Can you provide other useful details in that post? Is that a Unix timestamp? Is it UTC encoded and needs to be converted to local time? Does it really return as that particular string `/Date(...)/` and you need to parse out the numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the number of milliseconds since epoch.

This function extracts a number from a string, and returns a Date object created from that time number.

```
function dateFromStringWithTime(str) {
    var match;
    if (!(match = str.match(/\d+/))) {
        return false;
    }
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime (match[0] - 0);
    return date;
}
```

For example,

```
console.log(dateFromStringWithTime('/Date(1283457528340)/').toString());
```

The output is:

```
Fri Sep 03 2010 02:58:48 GMT+0700 (ICT)
```

Comment: It's preferable to maintain braces (`{}`) around `if` statement result blocks to maintain absolute compatibility, despite that the standard allows us to omit them.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. What does that value represent? Assuming UNIX timestamp milliseconds (adjust otherwise), you can extract the value, then apply `parseInt` and construct a new `Date` object with it.

```
var str     = "/Date(1283457528340)/";
var matches = str.match(/([0-9]+)/);
var d       = parseInt(matches[0]);
var obj     = new Date(d);
```

You should then be able to use the `Date` object as normal.
This is untested and may have typos/bugs, but the idea should be sound.

**Edit:** `matches[1]` -> `matches[0]`

Comment: Also note that I am not performing any validation or error handling here.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseJsonDate(jsonDate) {
    var epochMillis = jsonDate;
    var d = new Date(parseInt(epochMillis.substr(6)));
    return d;
}
```

The code above will give you a date formatted in a way that is useful in a given view.

The parameter passed into the function  (`jsonDate`) is the string you are trying to convert and the line `return d` is returning the date formatted nicely.

Simply another way to get the date you need.